# Redux form not resetting field

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a redux form, where on clicking a checkbox I show or hide part of the form. When showing or hiding the form I would also like to reset fields, but that doesn't seem to work. This is the checkbox field:

```
<CheckboxField
  key="willUseManuelLetter"
  name="willUseManuelLetter"
  label={{ id: 'HandlingForm.willUseManuelLetter' }}
  onChange={this.onToggle}
  readOnly={readOnly}
/>
```

And this are the fields that I show or hide depending on the state of the checkbox field:

```
<TextAreaField
  name="summary"
  label={{ id: 'HandlingForm.Summary' }}
  maxLength={200}
  rows={1}
  readOnly={readOnly}
  className={styles.smallTextArea}
/>

<TextAreaField
  name="longText"
  label={{ id: 'HandlingForm.LongText' }}
  maxLength={5000}
  readOnly={readOnly}
/>
```

In the `onToggle` function I have tried to reset the fields like this:

```
onToggle() {
  this.setState({
    willUseManuelLetter: !this.state.willUseManuelLetter,
  });

  const { handlingFormPrefix} = this.props;

  this.props.reduxFormChange(
    `${handlingFormPrefix}.HandlingForm`, 'summary',
    undefined,
  );

  this.props.reduxFormChange(
    `${handlingFormPrefix}.HandlingForm`, 'longText',
    undefined,
  );
}
```

But, this is not working, I am not resetting any fields, if I hide and again show the fields, I have the same values that I had before I have hid it. How should I do that?

Comment: Do you use any third party plugin like redux-form or anything else???

Comment: If you are using redux-form there are several options available....I tend to use option (D) https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.8/docs/faq/howtoclear.md/

Comment: @Sagar yes, I am using plugin redux-form, that is why I have tagged the question with redux-form

Comment: @Intellidroid I only need to clear some fields, not the whole form

Comment: would you not simply need to update the form state in redux (with action creator etc)? https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.2/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/

Comment: or the reducer plugin https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.2/docs/api/reducerplugin.md/

Answer (score 0):

You need to import reset from redux-form and dispatch it.
Try this

```
import { reset } from 'redux-form';
 .....
onToggle() {
  this.setState({
    willUseManuelLetter: !this.state.willUseManuelLetter,
  });
      dispatch(reset('formName'));
  }
```